# FXCM Connection Error - Cannot connect to server

Tags: python, api

I am trying to connect to FXCM throuhg an api and am constantly getting an error:

```
|ERROR|2020-01-11 20:42:41,825|Socket returns an error: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')")).
```

The code is :

```
import fxcmpy
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from datetime import date
import numpy as np

TOKEN = "hidden"
con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token=TOKEN, log_level='error')
```

I have been using this for a while now but error suddenly showed up today. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem. I got an email from api@fxcm.com below.

*"We did a release on demo on 1/12 to improve the Rest API.
With that said, Our REST API wrapper fxcmpy has been updated, you need to install the latest fxcmpy version at 1.2.6.
Here is the link where you can find the library: https://pypi.org/project/fxcmpy/#files
Please have in mind that just with pip install fxcmpy it might not work as it won’t update the library, please use below command."*

pip install –U fxcmpy